# How can checking out a different branch result in new untracked files?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have come across two Git situations that do not make sense to me.

1. There are some `untracked` files which show up only when we checkout a certain branch. Since they are untracked and checking out another branch applies changes only to the Working directory why they disappear when checking out other branches?  Untracked files should be there untouched...
2. Is there any case that `git pull` creates untracked files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's most likely because your `.gitignore` is different on the two branches.